# Service calls are happening one after the other even when some logic is written in between , Why?

Tags: angular

I am stuck in a scenario where I am making 2 calls to HTTP services, but between these 2 I have some logic to be executed.

My TS -

```
this.exampleService.saveDetails(Input).subscribe(res=>{
    this.intID = Number(res);
});

for(let scenario of this.currentScenario){

  var Input = <Input>{
    .....
  }

  this.Service.saveDTL(dtlInput).subscribe(res=>{
    this.Response = res;
  });
```

When the control comes to the first call, i.e.

```
this.Service.Details(Input).subscribe(res=>{
    this.ID = Number(res);
});
```

Before getting the response, the control goes to the for loop and then to the second service call -

```
this.Service.saveDTL(Input).subscribe(res=>{
    this.Response = res;
});
```

And then comes back to the first call after this. Because of this, I am not able to pass the response that I received from the first call to the second call.

My Service file -

```
     public save(Input : Input):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.Url + 'api/options/save' , Input); 
  }

  public saveDetail(Input: Input){
    return this.http.post<any[]>(this.Url + 'api/save-dtl' , Input);
  }
```

Can anyone please help me out of this?

Answer (score 1):

I would've done something like this:

```js
this.queryOptionsService.saveHDRDetails(headerInput).pipe(
  switchMap((res)=> {
    let intHDRID = Number(res);
    let observables = [];
    for(let criteria of this.currentCriteria){

      let dtlInput = <DTLInput>{
        criteriaHeaderId : intHDRID,
        fieldId : criteria.fieldId,
        value1 : criteria.fieldValue1,
        value2 : criteria.fieldValue2,
        compare :  criteria.compareOperator,
        operator : criteria.andOROperator,
        bemsId : this.bemsid
      }
    
      observables.push(this.queryOptionsService.saveDTL(dtlInput))
    }
    return forkJoin(observables)
  })
).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);
});
```

`switchMap`: to make http requests sequentially

`forkJoin`: to combine the observables that you traverse in the for loop.